# Webpack 2 Code Spliting with Server Side Rendering and React-Router-v4

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, universal, code-splitting

Using webpack2.2.0-rc1 and react routerv4, and using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194) to make code spliting to work, which states the following

```
function asyncComponent(getComponent) {
  return class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    static Component = null;
    state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        getComponent().then(Component => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component
          this.setState({ Component })
        })
      }
    }
    render() {
      const { Component } = this.state
      if (Component) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
      return null
    }
  }
}

const Foo = asyncComponent(() =>
  System.import('./Foo').then(module => module.default)
)
```

It actually  works, but  I am using server side rendering. So on the server I require component A, then on the client I System.import component A.
FInally when I access the lazy loaded route I get this react reuse markup warning because the client rendered 
initially loaded null from https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194#file-app-js-L21
while loading Component A. 

`Warning: React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and the markup generated on the server was not what the client was expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure out why the markup being generated is different on the client or server:
 (client) CO 0.0.0 </h1></div><!-- react-empty: 6 -
 (server) CO 0.0.0 </h1> </div><div data-radium="tru`

How can I make this work without errors?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed this [line](https://gist.github.com/acdlite/a68433004f9d6b4cbc83b5cc3990c194#file-app-js-L21) on the AsyncComponent to make it return a brake tag 
 while the code-splitted component is not loaded yet.Then instead of requiring the actual component to render server side, I just throw another brake tag, so the markup actually matches.

This is far from ideal

```
export function Shell(Component) {
    return React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Bar/>
                    <Component {...this.props}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    });
};

export const Waiting = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Bar/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});


// Client routes
const AsyncDash = Utils.asyncRoute(() => System.import("../components/dashboard/dashboard.tsx"));
const AsyncLogin = Utils.asyncRoute(() => System.import("../components/login/login"));

const routes = () => {
    return (<div>
            <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Shell(AsyncLogin)}/>
            <Match exactly pattern="/dashboard" component={Shell(AsyncDash)}/>
        </div>
    );
};


// Server routes
const routes = () => {
    return (<div>
            <Match exactly pattern="/" component={Waiting}/>
            <Match exactly pattern="/dashboard" component={Waiting}/>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Have you come across a solution for this?

Comment: Lots of solutions. React-async-component, old hack. Just don't. React-loadable, new hack. React-universal-component even better new hack.